# Creating folders from array of strings

Tags: bash, git-bash

I'm trying to create folders given an array of strings. I know it's a newbie question but I'm just starting bash scripting.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a lessons=(
  "Lesson 1 - Arrays" 
  "Lesson 2 - Classes"
)

for i in ${lessons[@]}
do
  mkdir $i
done
```

Comment: Quote all expansions - `for i in "${lessons[@]}";  do mkdir "$i"; done`

Comment: Actually, any POSIX `mkdir` will accept a series of strings as argument.  So, just replace the whole loop with the statement: `mkdir "${lessons[@]}"`

Comment: both worked can you create the answer so I can up vote them?